# Difference between using - and -- as options to set while setting positional params

Tags: linux, bash, shell

In man bash it is mentioned that `set` has two options `-` and `--`

I was wondering if there is any difference while using `-` and `--` as options to `set` while setting positional parameters.

I could not find any big difference mentioned in man bash when it comes to their usage in setting positional params.

Comment: Not entirely sure I get the question. Generally speaking, a lot of command line utilities have two forms of each parameter. For example, `-i` and `--interactive` might mean the same thing for a particular command line utility.

Comment: I understand that, but its not what I am asking. Can you check man bash and look for set options there, please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bash(1) man page for 4.1.5(1) says:

```
--      If no arguments follow this option, then the  positional
        parameters are unset.  Otherwise, the positional parame‐
        ters are set to the args, even if  some  of  them  begin
        with a -.
-       Signal  the  end of options, cause all remaining args to
        be assigned to the positional parameters.  The -x and -v
        options are turned off.  If there are no args, the posi‐
        tional parameters remain unchanged.
```

The first difference is when there are no arguments after the `-` or `--`. For the former, the existing positional parameters will be unchanged. For the latter, the positional parameters will be cleared.

So `set --` clears the positional parameters and `set -` is a no-op.

The `-v` and `-x` settings may be modified by `set - ...`. So, if you had `set -v` turned on (which causes the shell to print input lines as they are read), it will be turned off by the `set - ...` command. `set -- ...` will leave it unchanged.

`set -x` is more common that `set -v` in that `set -x` is often used to debug scripts to see exactly what commands are being run. Quite often when debugging a shell script, you would run it with `bash -x <script>`. Knowing that `set - ...` turns `-x` off, you'd probably want to use `set -- ...`, since it would be quite unexpected to have `-x` turned off as a side effect of another command.

Comment: So I guess there is no difference in using either of them while setting parameters.

Comment: @abc: Yes there is a difference. `set - ...` turns off `-x` and `-v`. This is likely not desirable as a side-effect, so I would use `set -- ...`

Answer (score 9):

You use `--` (double minus) to indicate the end of shell options and the start of arguments.  Hence, for example:

```
set -- -a -b -f somefile
```

After this, `$1` is `-a`, `$2` is `-b`, `$3` is `-f` and `$4` is `somefile`.

Without the `--`, the shell would interpret `-a`, `-b` and `-f` as shell options, and would set `$1` to `somefile`.

The Bash (4.1) manual says (of `set`):

> `--` If no arguments follow this option, then the positional parameters
>   are unset. Otherwise, the positional parameters are set to the arguments,
>   even if some of them begin with a ‘`-`’.
>
> `-` Signal the end of options, cause all remaining arguments to be
>   assigned to the positional parameters. The ‘`-x`’ and ‘`-v`’ options
>   are turned off. If there are no arguments, the positional parameters
>   remain unchanged.

Comment: Thanks for quoting from bash manpage. So - signals end of options, not -- . What difference would it make if I use - instead of -- for the example you have given.

Comment: @abc: `-` apparently just add to parameters, and resets `-a` `-x` `-v`

Answer (score 2):

The *convention* is to use a single `-` for single-letter arguments, e.g. `-i` and double `--` for their full-worded counterpart, e.g. `--interactive`.

See [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html) for more information.

This has been answered very well [elsewhere](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/70357/command-line-options-style-posix-or-what) on the StackExchange network.

**UPDATE**

The double-dash `--` prefixes long (verbatim) options to commands, but when used with a Bash builtin (like `set`), it means the end of options to that particular command.

E.g. if you want to create a file that starts with a dash:

```
touch -dashed
```

...you'll get an error:

```
touch: illegal option -- h
usage: touch [-acfm] [-r file] [-t [[CC]YY]MMDDhhmm[.SS]] file ...
```

However, try it with `--`, et voila:

```
touch -- -dashed
```

...and then `ls` to see `-dashed` in your current directory.

See [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/special-chars.html#DOUBLEDASHREF) for more information.

Comment: Not what I am asking, see my comment above.

Comment: Oh, I get it now. You mean the `set` Bash built-in. I'll adapt my answer, and I'll modify your answer to make it clearer.

Comment: also usually single letter params take parameter values like `-a 5` and more than single letter params take values with equal sign `--after=5`.

Answer (score 1):

In my `bash` manpage there is a sentence: `An argument of - is equivalent to --`.

Comment: I have `GNU bash, Version 4.0.35(1)-release`. It's in the man page at the very beginning (line 38).

Comment: This is different from `set` because there are no parameters before invoking `bash` (obviously), and `-a`, `-v`, `-x` setting comes from the command line.